# Как получить окончания порядковых имен числительных мужского пола?

Tags: php

Нужно добавить эти окончания к числам, к примеру 1-ый,2-ой,3-ий,4-ый,5-ый и т.д. Есть ли такая функция в PHP, если нет, то как сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Для решения Вашей задачи предлагаю воспользоваться следующим вариантом:

```
<?php
$number = 6;
function ordinal($number) {
    $ends = array('-ый','-ый','-ой','-ий','-ый','-ый','-ой','-ой','-ой');
    if ((($number % 100) >= 9) && (($number%100) <= 19))
        return $number. '-ый';
   elseif ($number <= 0)
       return $number. '-ой';
    else
        return $number. $ends[$number % 10];
}
echo ordinal($number);
```